# Any way to do this on a Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I have a list of strings such as this `x y z` and I want to transform it into `a/liba.lib b/libb.a c/libc.a`

Any ideas? (`$(INPUT:%=%/lib%.a)` yields `a/lib%.lib b/lib%.a c/lib%.a`, so don't bother trying that one).

Comment: I can't think of any reasonable transformation that will turn `x` into `a/liba.lib` other than `if (input=="x") return "a/liba.lib";`, which isn't a transformation at all - it's a replacement...

Answer (score 1):

```
INPUT := x y z
OUTPUT := $(foreach x,${INPUT},${x}/lib${x}.lib)

$(info INPUT=${INPUT})
$(info OUTPUT=${OUTPUT})
```

Outputs:

```
INPUT=x y z
OUTPUT=x/libx.lib y/liby.lib z/libz.lib
```

Comment: This will work, but I think the extra `$(call...)` is adding unnecessary complexity.  I would just use: `$(foreach x,$(INPUT),$x/lib$x.lib)`

Comment: @MadScientist Is your name Paul D. Smith?